# How to prevent Google Cloud Engine to run multiple concurrent instances?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Hi I'm deploying a very simple python code to Google App Engine just to test how Google App Engine works, that I'll later use for my real more complex code that I have tested locally. The problem is that Google App Engine logs is showing that I'm running multiple services / threads / instances / modules or whatever that name is... **CONCURRENTLY**

This is my code: **`main.py`**

```py
import time
    
def executeSomething():
    #code here
    print("Hello world!")
    time.sleep(5)
    
while True:
    executeSomething()
```

and `app.yaml`

```yaml
runtime: python38
service: default
handlers:
  - url: /
    script: auto
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

I deploy using `gcloud app deploy --stop-previous-version --version test-0-0-3`

Then I tail the logs using `gcloud app logs tail -s default`

```
    2022-08-09 15:59:18 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:18 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:18 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:18 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:23 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:23 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:23 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:23 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:28 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:28 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:28 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:28 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:33 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:33 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:33 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
    2022-08-09 15:59:33 default[test-0-0-3]  Hello world!
```

As you can see, there are 4 concurrent services running. Idk what is it called: services / threads / instances, but the problem is it's running several codes concurrently.

In my real code, I only want to run 1 service because I am afraid if I run multiple concurrently, it will create duplicates in the data I'm inserting to DB.

Comment: I would change to basic_scaling: max_instances: 1 to keep from spawning multiple instances.

Comment: Since you're still testing (and you want to avoid incurring costs), I would suggest using ```automatic_scaling``` instead of basic. Either way, you should set ```max_instances``` to  1

Comment: Since you are using App Engine Standard, you can set the [minimum instances as 0 and max instances to 1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#scaling_elements) .  That way you will force no more than one instance when the automatic scaling kicks in.

Comment: The main point of GAE is to be able to have concurrent instances.  If you don't want that, then use GCE.

Comment: I've tried `manual_scaling: instances: 1` this prints 4 concurrences but when I see App Engine's Instances, it's 2. Then I tried  `basic_scaling: max_instances: 1` this results to 0 instances and I don't see it printing the Hello World. Then I tried `automatic_scaling: max_instances: 1`, I don't see it printing the Hello World. Then I tried `automatic_scaling: min_instances: 0 max_instances: 1` still I don't see printing Hello world. All the last 3 sthows 0 instance on App Engine. Pls help.

Comment: @googlecloudsuportsucks I want to run a single python code in 1 instance, and I want to run it daily at certain time. What would you suggest me the easiest Google Cloud services to use? GCE with what for the cron job?

Comment: I just tried your code using ```automatic_scaling: max_instances: 1``` on my development server (ran the code with ```dev_appserver.py```) and my log file shows one instance of ```Hello World```. Note that I looked at my log file and didn't use the gcloud tailing command. To see an output, you should switch from ```print()``` to ```logging.info('Hello World')```. Don't forget to also set the log level to ```info``` after importing the logging module

Comment: @NoCommandLine What do you mean by development server? Do you do `gcloud app deploy`? I've tried again `automatic_scaling: max_instances: 1` and it still doesn't work. Come on anyone please help, I would love to share my screen and prove to you that it doesn't work...

Comment: By development server, i mean my Macbook (local machine)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, the OP wants to run a daily task with CRON jobs.  In this case, the number of instances doesn't matter and the CRON job will run only once.

You will see multiple instances at deployment, but with Google App Engine standard, you should have 0 or 1 paid instance running at all times and you should be easily able to say within the free quota.

GAE is a good solution for this task.

Comment: I'm not worried of the payment. What I'm worried is writing duplicates to DB. In my real code, every time the service is triggered, it writes to DB. If I have 4 concurrent instances, will it write 4 duplicates if I trigger it from cron?

Comment: As stated in my answer, the CRON job will only run once.  It doesn't matter how many instances you have.